# SoapUI REST Mock Service with SSL

Tags: rest, ssl, mocking, soapui

I'm having an issue with SoapUI 5.0.0. while trying to Mock a RESTFul service using SSL. Everything works fine if I don't use SSL at all.

In SoapUI preferences :

- I have enabled Mock SSL on port 8443 with the same keystores for Mock KeyStore and TrustStore.

In the mock service editor :

- path : /resource
- port : 8080
- host : localhost

In the mock action editor :

- method : GET
- resource path : /config

What I'm doing then is creating new REST service from URI with the following parameters :

- method : GET
- endpoint : `https://localhost:8443/resource`
- resource : /config

When I start the mock and call the request i get the following response generated by SoapUI instead of my mock content :

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta content="HTML Tidy for Java (vers. 26 sept. 2004), see www.w3.org" name="generator"/>
      <title/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>There are currently 1 running SoapUI MockServices</p>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <a href="/resource?WSDL">Mock</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
      <br/>
      <br/>
   </body>
</html>
```

Do you guys have an idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Setup the SoapUI REST Mock using HTTP, then run a MockServer Proxy (http://www.mock-server.com/) ahead of it to expose an HTTPS endpoint.
If you need to simulate a corporate firewall, start another MockServer to act as the corporate proxy!

eg.

SoapUI Mock on HTTP port 8003

MockServer Proxy on HTTPS port 8002, redirects to HTTP on port 8003

MockServer Proxy on HTTPS port 8001, redirects to HTTPS on port 8002 (simulates corporate proxy)

MockServer generates SSL certs or .jks which need to be added to your client application truststore to allow connection.

Comment: To forward from HTTPS to HTTP I used an expectation like
curl -v -X PUT "http://localhost:8083/mockserver-war-5.3.0/expectation" -d '{
    "httpRequest": {
        "path": "/path"
    },
    "httpForward": {
        "host": "localhost",
        "port": 8080,
        "scheme": "HTTP"
    }
}'

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately SSL is only implemented for SOAP mock services, not REST. There is a feature request for the latter. See: http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=25160

Comment: I'm sure this was probably true three years ago ... but SoapUI very definitely supports SSL for REST now.  For example, my version is SOAPUI 5.2.1, and REST/SSL works fine.

Comment: REST/SSL does not work for me with SoapUI 5.4.0.  I get the same behavior as OP.