# Does SoapUI 5.6.0 support REST mock service with SSL?

Tags: ssl, windows-10, soapui

When I use a SOAP mock service with SSL everything works fine. I have added .pfx files under *File -> Preferences -> SSL Settings* for both the *Mock KeyStore* and the *Mock TrustStore*. I use a C# WCF client to send requests to the SOAP service and I get replies back as expected. I can use Wireshark to see that both my client and the SoapUI mock service is exchanging certificates.

Now, I have created a REST mock service in SoapUi. I use Postman to send requests to my REST mock service and when I use the unencrypted url everything works fine. But when try the url that uses the certificates I get a reply back saying that *There are currently 1 running SoapUI MockServices*. I have included the urls so you can see the difference.

*http://localhost:8090/search* <- works fine

*http**s**://localhost:**8443**/search* <- does not work

Essentially I believe I have the exact [same situation as this guy had 7 years ago.](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/ReadyAPI-Questions/SoapUI-REST-Mock-Service-with-SSL/td-p/43051)  From SoapUi forum posts I can see that [version 5.4.0 apparently did not support REST mock services with SSl.](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/REST-Mock-Service-with-SSL-is-available-in-SoapUI-5-4-0/m-p/177940/highlight/true#M28237) On stackoverflow I can see [posts saying that REST mock services in SoapUi is a feature request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28235006/16955687), but the link in the post is dead.

Does anyone know if SoapUi 5.6.0 support REST mock services with SSL?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is apparently NO, SoapUI 5.6.0 does not support REST mock services with SSL. From version 5.4.0, SmartBear had no plans to include SSL for REST in future releases of SoapUI OS, [according to this forum post.](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/REST-Mock-Service-with-SSL-is-available-in-SoapUI-5-4-0/m-p/178014/highlight/true#M28244)

I ended up just creating my own ASP.NET webservice and configuring it to use certificates.